# How to get static URI with AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I can get a static resource like this with AppEngine:

```
InputStream is = 
    getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config/Reports.xml");
```

However, I need to get this static resource `URI` and pass it on to a Java class which is not a Servlet.

What is the strategy to pass URI if this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
URI uri = 
    getServletContext().getResource("/WEB-INF/config/Reports.xml").toURI();
```